# phpdoc crashes when functions are involved; how to debug phpdoc correctly

Tags: phpdoc

I just started using phpdoc. I installed it on windows using pear 1.10.1, php 7.1.1 and I have installed graphviz and set the path variable.

I am running phpdoc from the console with

```
   phpdoc -d "path" -t "path\doc"
```

When I am running phpdoc on the test file containing

```
   <?php
      /**
       * class.
       *
       */
       class test
       {
       }
   ?>
```

it compiles and produces a view-able html. 
The moment I switch 'class test' to 'function test()' phpdoc gives up on me and does not work. I dont even know how to debug all this stuff it puts out in the console!
What is the best way to debug/find the error? This is the error code:

```
  Execute transformation using writer "twig"
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\erus
ev\parsedown\Parsedown.php on line 1405
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Parsedown::$Array in C:\php\pear\phpDocumentor\
vendor\erusev\parsedown\Parsedown.php on line 1405
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Monolog\ErrorHandler:
:handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in
C:\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\ErrorHandler.php:12
2
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Monolog\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\ErrorHa
ndler.php on line 122
[2017-01-25 20:08:56] phpDocumentor.ALERT: Fatal Error (E_ERROR): Uncaught TypeE
rror: Argument 1 passed to Monolog\ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an in
stance of Exception, instance of Error given in C:\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor
\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\ErrorHandler.php:122 Stack trace: #0 [internal func
tion]: Monolog\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error)) #1 {main}   thrown {
"code":1,"message":"Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Monolog\\ErrorHandl
er::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given
in C:\\php\\pear\\phpDocumentor\\vendor\\monolog\\monolog\\src\\Monolog\\ErrorHa
ndler.php:122\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Monolog\\ErrorHandler->hand
leException(Object(Error))\n#1 {main}\n  thrown","file":"C:\\php\\pear\\phpDocum
entor\\vendor\\monolog\\monolog\\src\\Monolog\\ErrorHandler.php","line":122} []
```

which is followed by some html expression??
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

everything works by downloading phpdoc 2.9.0 manually (just googled it)!

apparently, the newest available version on pear (v2.8.5) does not work well with php7?!